# fabric js free drawing rectangle results in duplicate

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

hey guys so im creating a whiteboard app using fabric js but im facing this problem whenever the user draws a rectangle and selects to drag it, it actually drags another invisible rectangle and not the original rectangle which is super weird after i drag the duplicate invisible rectangle i then can freely drag the visible one.. which sucks. i actually made sure that this was the problem as after i drew the rectangle i did canvas.remove(rect) and it did remove the rectangle however the invisible rectangle stayed there.. here is the code:

```
$('#square').click(function () {
    tool = 'square';
    canvas.selection = false;
    changeStatus(false);
    //register mouse event
    // canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = 'transparent';
    canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
    canvas.on('mouse:down', onMouseDown);
    canvas.on('mouse:move', onMouseMove);
    canvas.on('mouse:up', onMouseUp);
});
$("#eraser").click(function()
{
    tool = 'eraser';
    canvas.selection = true;
    canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
    changeStatus(true);
    //remove mouse event
    canvas.off('mouse:down', onMouseDown);
    canvas.off('mouse:move', onMouseMove);
    canvas.off('mouse:up', onMouseUp);
}); 
function onMouseDown(o) {
      console.warn('clicked');
      isMouseDown = true;
      var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
      if (tool == 'square') {
          rect = new fabric.Rect({
              left: pointer.x,
              top: pointer.y,
              width: 0,
              height: 0,
              stroke: 'red',
              strokeWidth: 3,
              selectable: false,
              fill: ''
          });
          canvas.add(rect);
      }
  }
function onMouseMove(o) {
    if (!isMouseDown) {
        return;
    }
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    if (tool == 'square') {
        rect.set({
            width: (Math.abs((pointer.x - rect.get('left')))),
            height: (Math.abs((pointer.y - rect.get('top'))))
        });
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
function onMouseUp(o) {
    if (tool == 'square') {
        rect.setCoords();
        console.log(rect);
    }
    isMouseDown = false;
}
```

just to clarify a bit more[image: the duplicate]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = 'transparent';
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
```

`canvas.isDrawingMode = true;` here drawing mode is on and the color is transparent , so it is not visible and creating another bounding box according to your mouse move(Pencil path object).

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c'),isMouseDown,tool;
$('#square').click(function () {
  tool = 'square';
  canvas.selection = false;
  changeStatus(false);
  //register mouse event
  // canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
  //canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = 'transparent';
  //canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
  canvas.on('mouse:down', onMouseDown);
  canvas.on('mouse:move', onMouseMove);
  canvas.on('mouse:up', onMouseUp);
});
$("#select").click(function()
{
  tool = 'select';
  canvas.selection = true;
  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
  changeStatus(true);
  //remove mouse event
  canvas.off('mouse:down', onMouseDown);
  canvas.off('mouse:move', onMouseMove);
  canvas.off('mouse:up', onMouseUp);
}); 
function onMouseDown(o) {
    console.warn('clicked');
    isMouseDown = true;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    if (tool == 'square') {
        rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: pointer.x,
            top: pointer.y,
            width: 0.1,
            height: 0.1,
            stroke: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 3,
            selectable: false,
            fill: ''
        });
        canvas.add(rect);
    }
}

function changeStatus(val){
  canvas.forEachObject(function (obj){
   obj.selectable = val;
  })
  canvas.renderAll();
 }
function onMouseMove(o) {
  if (!isMouseDown) {
      return;
  }
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  if (tool == 'square') {
      rect.set({
          width: (Math.abs((pointer.x - rect.left))),
          height: (Math.abs((pointer.y - rect.top)))
      });
      canvas.renderAll();
  }
}
function onMouseUp(o) {
  if (tool == 'square') {
      rect.setCoords();
      console.log(rect);
  }
  isMouseDown = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.7/fabric.js"></script>
<button id='square'>square</button>
<button id='select'>select</button>
<canvas id='c' width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: works but still not ideall because if i try to put the cursor in the rectangle after i draw it i can still see the dragging icon which isnt ideal for ux experience any idea how we can make it so that the drag icon doesnt appear when we have the square tool selected? :/

Comment: You can change using `hoverCursor` property

Comment: thanks so far this has been working however i have the pencil tool is it possible to make isDrawingMode work but without duplicating it? because with drawing mode drawing the rectangle is alot smoother